# Writing huge rows into a file

Tags: java, postgresql, memory-leaks, resultset, printwriter

I have a huge result set including , let's say, 1 million rows. I normally use the following snippet in order to write them into a file, whereas I am always out of memory. Are there any effective ways to eliminate this problem ?

```
 PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(filename, "UTF-8");
 iteration -> { writer.println(a single string); }

 writer.close();
```

Comment: Investigate buffering. That way you're only consuming as much memory as you desire.

Comment: Try flushing the writer after printing.

Comment: Dont do the entire file at once. Break it into chunks.

Comment: @MaxMega close() is supposed to flush().

Comment: Do you really mean that the entire result is in a single (!) string (a String)?

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Oh yes, you're right, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said ResultSet, I take it this is coming from a database? First, use a streaming result set. MySQL's JDBC driver likes to buffer *all* rows in memory, and with 1M (or 1B) rows, this can be a problem.

If you want this to scale, do it in a threaded way. Have one thread, the producer, reading rows from the ResultSet, and another, the consumer, writing rows to the file. Something like an ArrayBlockingQueue is great for this. If the consumer can't keep up with the producer, start blocking, and wait from the consumer to catch up. This approach takes less memory and is faster, since your IO is being done in parallel.

Comment: The same is true with PostgreSQL btw. You'll want to set a fetchSize.